# Function expression using a name

Tags: javascript, function

Here's the exercise:

> Create an arnoldYells function. This function should:
>
> - take one argument, a name, as a string
> - return the string `"Get to the choppa <name>!"`

---

Here's what I have, is this correct?

```
 function arnoldYells (Sasha){
     return "Get to the choppa <name>!" ;
 }
```

Comment: *"is this correct"*: Well, does it return the correct value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the argument in the function - note that I am including the call to the function in a console.log so that it will show you the returned value.

So to break it down - you call the function arnoldYells and pass the string to it as the argument (you could have this as a user created string from a text input or such). The function then takes that argument, puts it into the string inside the function and returns the entire value (created string) to the calling origin. This then logs the entire returned string into the the console.

```js
console.log( arnoldYells('Sasha') );

function arnoldYells (name){
     return "Get to the choppa " + name +"!";
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Gavgrif! This was very helpful!